# Spring boot configuration, fields mandatory

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I try to validate required fields with configuration yaml (spring boot 2.4.5 and java 8)

here an example of what I whant to do:

```
public class ObjectToTest {
    private String stringToTest;
    private SubObjectToTest subObjectToTest;
}
```

And my configuration yml:

```
mandatory-fields:
  config_one:
    - name: stringToTest
      required: true
    - name: subObjectToTest
      required: false
  config_two:
    - name: stringToTest
      required: false
    - name: subObjectToTest
      required: true
```

in this example, for `config_one`, `stringToTest` can't be empty or null, but with `config_two` it can be null

I don't want to use introspection, I just want to know if there is a way to do that

Thanks by advence

Comment: Hi! You want to map the ObjectToTest with the data available in the yaml or you just want to check if you have the required fields in the yaml file?

Comment: I want to check my object have values, because it has required: true

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to perform validations directly on the yaml file and load properties based on another properties. I would try to load all the configurations and then I would iterate and validate if I should evaluate one config or another. Maybe this can help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation